# How can I dynamically define a source for an ActiveRecord has_many relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Given the ActiveRecord model below:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_assignments
  has_many :product_assignments
  # Only one of the next two should appear, based on condition
  has_many :products, through: :product_assignments
  has_many :products, through: :group_assignments
end
```

Would like to define the last has_many...through relation based on the following condition: if the model has any product assignments associated to it, then products come from product assignments. If the model has no product_assignments, then products come from group_assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not going to happen.  The methods are at the class level but then you want to base the decision to define more class level relations depending upon conditions  of an instance.

What you can do however is keep the 2 and have methods that merge them together:

```
has_many :pa_products, through: :product_assignments, source: :products
has_many :ga_products, through: :group_assignments, source: :products

def products
  (pa_products + ga.products).uniq
end
```